Using EU LED lamp in USA
I live in the US but recently purchased a European LED lamp intending to rewire it to US standards.  When the lamp arrived, I noticed that the end of the power chord said the following:
LED DRIVER
INPUT: 100-240V~ 50/60Hz 0.35A Max
OUTPUT: 12.0V 1.0A 12.0W
Since it seemed to be dual voltage, I ended up buying a simple adapter and plugging it in and it seemed to work fine.  But the manufacturer's website and the paperwork that came with the lamp all say not to use in the US, and the manufacturer makes it fairly hard to even buy the lamp from the US.  In fact, the paperwork indicates the lamp is single voltage.

Any idea why the manufacturer would try to restrict sale/use of the lamp in the US?

Any danger to the lamp or my home if I use it in the US?  Should I get it rewired anyway?



Best guess: wide-range power supply but never paid for UL certification. Electrically not an issue if you plug it in it will shine as you have noticed, only legal/insurance related.

The lamp is made under EU standards and tested for compliance and safety with EU standards and regulation, if sold by a reputable company.
The point is that even if the standards are similar and EU devices are tested with higher voltage than US requirement, the problem is since it has not been tested and verified to pass regulations for sale and use in US, you are trying to use a device not tested and intended for your market.
So it means that even if the device had been tested with stricter tests to be safer than US requirements, it is still untested as per your laws and regulations.
In some jurisdictions, it makes you as the importer of the device and you might be held responsibile of the safety of the device and if it passes regulations.
Unless you bought this from a e-commerce site from an oriental seller - they sometimes do not even know what they are selling and the description is garbage, and the lamp might not even pass EU regulations.
I guess the bottom line is, if the device burns down your house, and insurance investigators figure out you bought and used an device not in compliance with local regulations, you might be on your own.
(Basically same thing with car lamps - slightly different regulations, and the headlights may be identical - but the ones sold in EU are have only EU approval markings and the ones sold in US have only US approval markings, hence making it useless to try buing headlights overseas, as you can't legally use non-approved parts).
